# Multiple GCM receivers - Push doesn't work sometimes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have two GCM receivers in my app. One of them is used by urbanAirship and the other is used by our application for another service. I am experiencing a strange problem now. Sometimes push notifications work for an installation and if i try to uninstall and install it again, i don't receive anything. I guess it has to do with GCM registration token but i don't see any errors for that in the logs.
Here are my receivers for GCM in the manifest file

```
<!-- GMS native receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="my_package_name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".services.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.MyInstanceIdListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>
```

and this is the receiver for the library

```
receiver android:name=".ninja.push.IntentReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.CHANNEL_UPDATED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.DISMISSED" />

                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Check in App server (Token will be update each time in table that mean you will get dynamically token from server and send that token to app server)

Comment: @Vishnu but it works fine if i remove the other receiver.

Comment: Why not use single receiver(lets say Service) and from there you can broadcast the event!

Comment: @SayedHassan Does it show some InvalidRegistration errors on the server side? If it shows some then it might be the cause.